# AngularJS ngrepeat and directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to draw a menu using a AngularJS directive and `ngRepeat`

This is my controller and directive:

```
angular.module('root', [])
  .controller('sideMenu', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.menuItems = [
      { name: 'TRACTION', id: 1 },
      { name: 'CONVERSION', id: 2 },
      { name: 'FINANCIALS', id: 3 },
      { name: 'USAGE', id: 4 }
    ];
  }])
  .directive('menuItem', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        item: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'elements/sidebar.html'
    };
  });
```

**elements/sidebar.html**

```
<a href="#{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</a>
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="leftSide" ng-controller="sideMenu">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in menuItems">
      <menu-item item="{{item.name}}"></menu-item>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is not displaying anything at the moment, I do see that the ng-repeat is working by creating 4 `<li>` elements but the directive does not work.

Before I used the ng-repeat I listed each menu item and had to have separate `$scope` items, I wanted to move all elements in an array and loop through them with `ngRepeat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `item="{{item.name}}"` to `item="item.name"`

you dont need it since it's a [bi-directional reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)

Comment: Actually had to change it to `item="item"`. Works now, thank you. Is there a more 'correct' way to do this in AngularJS?

Comment: That seems to be the most _correct_ way to do it to me.